# Ansible Jinja2 template iteration over loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
{% if node_count is defined %}
{% set cnt = node_count|int + 1 %}
{% for i in range(cnt)  %}
            localhost00{{ i + 1 }}.local
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I wanted to print like

```
localhost001.local
localhost002.local
.
.
localhost010.local
```

I know thats not the right way I'm doing, when count reaches 10 its printing `localhost0010.local`, I wanted it to print `localhost010.local`

Appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use formatting to print out leading zeros. You can do that like this:

```
{% set node_count = 10 %}
{% if node_count is defined %}
    {% set cnt = node_count|int + 1 %}
    {% for i in range(cnt) %}
        localhost{{ '%03d' % (i + 1) }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Just change the 3 to however many "digits" you need.

Output:

```
localhost001
localhost002
localhost003
localhost004
localhost005
localhost006
localhost007
localhost008
localhost009
localhost010
localhost011
```